# Express JS: Can I still have <scripts> in my index.html

Tags: javascript, express

When converting an index.html page to be served up by Express, instead of Webstorm, I noticed that all my scripts suddenly reported `404 - Not Found`, where previously they were found just fine.

Should I not be serving up a page from Express that has a bunch of  tags? If it is OK to do so, how come they are all `404-Not found` now, where previously they were found just fine?

EDIT: Directory structure:

`project
    --- src
        --- js
            main.js
        --- css
        index.html
        app.js <-- all the express code`

Express code includes these lines:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to serve scripts. just remember, you have to set up express to serve them, the same way you set it up to serve index.html. (though, it'd likely be better to have a folder with all of your static assets and have nginx, iis, or apache serve them.)

Comment: Can you provide a directory structure? It sounds like its setting the root of your project to something different, or they aren't being served right.

Comment: I've updated with the directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Express is set up to serve your static assets. By default it will serve these from `/public`

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

You can add your scripts there (recommended!) or add additional `express.static` statements pointing to your specific scripts folder.